# Why data initialization should not be done in the constructor of the component in Angular?

Tags: angular, constructor, angular6, ngoninit

I am new to Angular 6. I have a requirement that I need to initialize all the drop-down fields through API calls. Many developers suggest that api calls for the data initialization should be done inside the ngOninit rather than doing it through constructor? Can anyone please let me know the reason behind this ?

Answer (score 3):

This is because the `constructor` is called to initialize the class and **not** the component. The `constructor` is called before `ngOnInit` , at this point the `component` hasn’t been created yet, only the `component` class has being instantiated thus your dependencies are brought in, but your initialization code will not run.

To ensure your initialization code runs, simply put it in the `ngOnInit` which is the lifecycle hook method of a component in `angular` ensuring that the component has been created successfully.

Comment: Hi Sarthak, Thanks for the reply. Also, Could you explain me a bit about AfterViewInit(), AfterViewChecked(), AfterContentInit(), and AfterContentChecked(). I am a bit confused between this as I am not sure when to use this?

Comment: please refer to this [link](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/components/lifecycle-hooks/) and let me know if it helps.

Comment: @SarthakAggarwal, does it make a difference for properties whose value will not change for the lifetime of the application -- for instance, static info in a footer?

Answer (score 1):

`constructor` method on a class (or TypeScript in this case) is a feature of a class itself, rather than an Angular feature. It’s out of Angular’s control when the constructor is invoked

> constructor invoke when the new instant of the class created but this
>   doesn't mean angular finish finalized the component and binding

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({})
class ExampleComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {}

  // called on demand by Angular
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('ngOnInit fired');
  }
}

const instance = new ExampleComponent();

// Angular calls this when necessary
instance.ngOnInit();
```

Note that JavaScript engine calls the constructor, not Angular directly. Which is why the ngOnInit (and $onInit in AngularJS) lifecycle hook was created.

`ngOnInit` is purely there to give us a signal that Angular has finished initialising the component.

This phase includes the first pass at Change Detection against the properties that we may bind to the component itself - such as using an @`Input()` decorator.

Due to this, the @Input() properties are available inside ngOnInit, however are **`undefined`** inside the constructor

> The ngOnInit lifecycle hook is a guarantee that your bindings are
>   readily available.

from doc

> Initialize the directive/component after Angular first displays the
>   data-bound properties and sets the directive/component's input
>   properties. Called once, after the first ngOnChanges().

**[Lifecycle sequence](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks)**

1. ngOnChanges()
2. ngOnInit()
3. ngDoCheck()
4. ngAfterContentInit()
5. ngAfterContentChecked()
6. ngAfterViewInit()
7. ngAfterViewChecked()

[toddmotto - Angular constructor versus ngOnInit](https://toddmotto.com/angular-constructor-ngoninit-lifecycle-hook)

[The essential difference between Constructor and ngOnInit in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/the-essential-difference-between-constructor-and-ngoninit-in-angular-c9930c209a42)